# Storing data into arrays and checking to see if it is a valid integer

Tags: c#

I am currently working with storing data into arrays. The program takes the information from a text files and then formats the result with product name. The issues is that if other than a number(int) is found in the starting line of the text the file breaks. Specifically at `productID = Convert.ToInt16(storeData[0]);`. How can I avoid breaking the program if the first character in the text file is other than an integer?

how the info looks in the text file: ProductID, Month and Sales

`1 5 20.00`

**CODE**

```
string[] productName = new string[100];
                string arrayLine;
                int[] count = new int[100];
                int productID = 0;
                double individualSales = 0;
                double[] totalSales = new double[100];
                double[] totalAverage = new double[100];

                productName[1] = "Cookies";
                productName[2] = "Cake";
                productName[3] = "Bread";
                productName[4] = "Soda";
                productName[5] = "Soup";
                productName[99] = "Other";                                      

                while ((arrayLine = infile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {


                    string[] storeData = arrayLine.Split(' ');

                    productID = Convert.ToInt16(storeData[0]);
                    individualSales = Convert.ToDouble(storeData[2]);

                    if (stateName[productID] != null)
                    {
                        count[productID] += 1;
                        totalSales[stateID] += individualSales;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count[99] += 1;
                        totalSales[99] += individualSales;
                    }


                }
                infile.Close();
```

Comment: Side notes: your sample code contains way too much stuff not related to the question, please try to make it smaller (5-7 lines is the best). `Convert.ToInt16` produces `short`, if you actually expect `int` values use `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!Int16.TryParse(storeData[0], out productID))
   continue;//or do something else
```

[Int16.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.tryparse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

as Gromer stated, I'd rather use `int.TryParse` (which is in fact `Int32.TryParse`)...

Comment: I would suggest `int.TryParse` or `Int32.TryParse`, as the `int` can store up to a signed 32-bit integer value.

Comment: Yeah, I was just suggesting that kind of to the whole question, not specifically you.  I know that the code in the question used `Int16`.

Answer (score 1):

Try and replace `productID = Convert.ToInt16(storeData[0]);` with:

```
if (Int16.TryParse(storeData[0], out productID))
{
     //do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TryParse can help you out:

```
if(Int16.TryParse(storeData[0], out productId))
{
    //do stuff
}
else
{
    //wasn't valid
}
```